# How to avoid using all RAM by mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

During mongodb index creation  machine becomes very slow.  "Top" command shows that mongodb uses 98% of RAM. I have closed ssh session and after that I can't login by ssh anymore.

System info:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.4 
8 GB RAM
2.7 TB free on HDD
```

MongoDB info:

```
> db.stats();
{
        "db" : "poi",
        "collections" : 11,
        "objects" : 68429619,
        "avgObjSize" : 480.50437612402897,
        "dataSize" : 32880731386,
        "storageSize" : 14584963072,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 55,
        "indexSize" : 5711147008,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

And what does it mean? Can it be the reason?

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2016-06-01T07:51:38.371+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-01T07:51:38.371+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2016-06-01T07:51:38.371+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2016-06-01T07:51:38.371+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-01T07:51:38.372+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-01T07:51:38.372+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems:
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **              numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-06-01T07:51:38.373+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Comment: could you provide more details? amount of ram, collection size, index size? Even car, when has 15 person instead of 5 runs slowly :-)

Comment: MongoDB will _always_ balance out at between 85% and 90% of physical RAM, when enough RAM is available and the working set has an according size. WiredTiger will need double the RAM it usually needs if you have journaling enabled, which is the default. Additionally, it needs at least 1GB for its cache. From the values you write, I'd guess your machine is vastly under dimensioned. $5 on less than 4GB of RAM, most likely 2.

Comment: As people mentioned, your machine is most likely under provisioned so your best bet is to increase RAM. however you can mitigate this issue by increasing swap space for time being. It's not a best solution but atleast system will let you in.

Comment: added all this information to topic